# ASP.NET Core | gRPC "Error starting gRPC call: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, network-programming, grpc

I have a local gRPC client and a remote gRPC server. Local gRPC client is running on IIS. Remote gRPC server runs on Kestrel inside Ubuntu OS. When I'm trying to make a gRPC call from client to server I'm getting **RpcException** with the following message `"Error starting gRPC call: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."`.

---

- The firewall on the gRPC server machine is disabled.
- I have successfully intercepted incoming network packages on gRPC server with **tcpdump** and they seem ok. That means packages are reaching server machine and they are blocked by the application.
- I can access index page of gRPC server from gRPC client machine using browser.
- gRPC server Kestrel uses a self-signed SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I have used port 31700 for gRPC server. Now I changed it to another one, and it works! I will appreciate some explanation of why is this port cannot be used for listening.

Comment: I have the Same problem, may you share your configuration?

Comment: I'm also interested!